# What is the sequence precedence of spring.cloud.config.label?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I can't seem to find any documentation of `spring.cloud.config.label` on spring cloud docs. Particularly if I provide spring.cloud.config.label=tag-1,tag-2,tag-3 which properties will win ?

Does tag-3 properties win over tag-1 properties or vice-versa ?

OR when the first existant tag succeeds ?

According to this
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_spring_cloud_config_client

> You can override all of them by setting spring.cloud.config.* (where * is name, profile or label). The label is useful for rolling back to previous versions of configuration. With the default Config Server implementation, it can be a git label, branch name, or commit ID. Label can also be provided as a comma-separated list. In that case, the items in the list are tried one by one until one succeeds. This behavior can be useful when working on a feature branch. For instance, you might want to align the config label with your branch but make it optional (in that case, use spring.cloud.config.label=myfeature,develop).

...it somewhat alludes in the lame poor attempt to slightly hint that 'myfeature' branch may not be present and it would still work because it would then fall back to "develop" branch. Or am I reading too much into it ? what happens if both the branches are present ? Are the properties merged ? or the first one win ?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the comma separated active profiles or imports URI it turns out Spring will stop at the first label (branch/tag) that results into a 200 response as per my experiments.

So as per my example `spring.cloud.config.label=tag-1,tag-2,tag-3` if trying `tag-1` results into error it will try `taq-2`. If `tag-2` results into a valid 200 response it will NOT try `tag-3`.

i.e. no merging between labels